# how to take (6+5) as a single input from user in python and display the result

Tags: python, user-input, addition

We are creating a calculator using python. I would like the user to input a number then operator then second number then the program prints out the result. For example, "User input calculation" ,User:5+9, and the computer prints out 14. I see its called the read-eval-print loop method. I need help converting that method into code and implemented.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple calculator example to help get you started.

```
while True:
    num1 = input('First Number: ')
    num2 = input('Second Number: ')
    op = input('Operator: ')

    try:
        num1 = int(num1)
        num2 = int(num2)
    except:
        print('Input a valid number!')
        continue

    if op not in ['+', '-', '*']:
        print('Invalid operator!')
        continue

    if op == '+':
        print(str(num1 + num2))
    elif op == '-':
        print(str(num1 - num2))
    elif op == '*':
        print(str(num1 * num2))
```

Comment: I need the program to recognize the operator '+' and assign it to addition. the user enters 6+9 and the program prints out the result.

Comment: @MikeLewis You an try the `str.split` method. For example:`num1, num2 = wholeString.split('+')`. If wholeString was equal to '6+9', the command would return the list `['6', '9']`. (good error check step) If the length of the result is not equal to two, It did not work.